# Can I use COUNT() and DISTINCT together?

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to count the number of rows from a mysql table and not to include duplicate entries,

Could I use `distinct` with `count()`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Sure.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column) FROM table;
```

Answer (score 15):

What you need is the following:

```
SELECT field_type_name, count(*) FROM fields GROUP BY field_type_name;
```

This will give you something like this:

```
image   14
string  75
text     9
```

Comment: Yeah... that yields 13 duplicates of `image`, 74 duplicates of `string` and 8 duplicates of `text`. Counting total rows in a table without certain duplicate entries is a different thing from counting rows for each of a certain type.

Answer (score 5):

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field) from Table
```

[See this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct).

Comment: is `COUNT (DISTINCT *)` a valid piece of a query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT column Name) as alias from table_Name;
```