# Calculate count of rows in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [COUNT() and DISTINCT can i use together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483798/count-and-distinct-can-i-use-together)

I have this sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (4,3) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'published')
```

and I get two rows with the same ID => expected

adding `GROUP BY wp_posts.ID` will reduce the count of rows to one

Now I would like to get the number of rows with and SQL query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (4,3) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'published')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

I'll get as result "2" instead of "1", even with the "GROUP BY".

What is the correct statement to get the numbers of rows from the first statement?

Comment: Why are you expecting a result of `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT wp_posts.ID) as cnt FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (4,3) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'published')
```

This will give you the count of unique IDs in result rows.

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

Since the first query displays 2 rows, the second query should return `2`, and it does. This is working as it should.

Comment: Yep the first query returns two rows but if I add "GROUP BY ID" I get a single row. If I add GROUP BY to the second query I still get two rows

Answer (score 0):

Having that GROUP BY there makes no real logical sense.

A simple fix would be to use your original sql as a subselect and do the count based on that:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt  
FROM (SELECT wp_posts.ID  
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships  
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
WHERE ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (4,3) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'  
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'published') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID) Sub1
```

Or the folowing might be OK, depending on the relationships between the tables (and so how unique wp_posts.ID is).

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT wp_posts.ID) 
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (4,3) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'published')
```