# How do I get the column count using another unique column?

Tags: mysql

I am collecting certain actions from site visitors. When I record the action, I store the user id and browser they are using.

I would like a count of how many times each browser was used, but if there are actions from the same user it will collect the same browser each time, so when it makes the count for each browser, I want it to only count the browser once for each user.

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user), browser, count(browser) AS browser_count
FROM tracking 
GROUP BY user, browser
```

This is what it returns:

```
user|browser|browser_count
--------------------------
20  |Chrome |   5
156 |Chrome |   127
156 |Firefox|   2
156 |IE     |   2   
156 |Safari |   2
160 |Chrome |   269
160 |Firefox|   8
160 |IE     |   4
160 |Opera  |   6
160 |Safari |   4
```

The results show that Chrome was recorded 5 times by user 20, 127 times by user 156, and 269 times by user 160. Instead, what I need is the total times Chrome was used, but only recording it once per user, which would make it only 3 times used total by unique users.

This is what I would like returned:

```
browser|browser_count
---------------------
Chrome | 3
Firefox| 2
IE     | 2   
Safari | 2
Opera  | 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total times Chrome was used, but only recording it once per user should be a count of distinct users grouped by browser:

```
SELECT browser,COUNT(DISTINCT user) AS browser_count
FROM tracking 
GROUP BY browser
```

EDIT: removed parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

The solution flows directly from [Can I use COUNT() and DISTINCT together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483798/can-i-use-count-and-distinct-together)

```
SELECT browser, COUNT(DISTINCT user)
    FROM tracking
    GROUP BY browser;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21e11/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
Select browser, sum(counter) as browser_count from 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT(user) as user, browser, 1 as counter AS browser_count
    FROM tracking 
    GROUP BY user, browser
)T group by browser
```

Or you should try,

```
Select browser, count(user) as browser_count from 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT(user) as user, browser, 1 as counter AS browser_count
        FROM tracking 
        GROUP BY user, browser
    )T group by browser
```